# Hiding axis labels in non-aggregate columns during drillown

Tags: highcharts

How do I manipulate the x-axis style on a drilled down chart in Highcharts?

For instance, given the following drilldown chart, how do I hide the x-axis labels in the drilled down version of the chart (that appears when you click one of the columns)?

In general, it seems like there are are not a lot of ways to control the layout of the drilled down chart, is that correct?

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Basic drilldown'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'

  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Things',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: 'Animals',
      y: 5,
      drilldown: 'animals'
    }, {
      name: 'Fruits',
      y: 2,
      drilldown: 'fruits'
    }, {
      name: 'Cars',
      y: 4,
      drilldown: 'cars'
    }]
  }],
  drilldown: {
    series: [{
      id: 'animals',
      data: [
        ['Cats', 4],
        ['Dogs', 2],
        ['Cows', 1],
        ['Sheep', 2],
        ['Pigs', 1]
      ]
    }, {
      id: 'fruits',
      data: [
        ['Apples', 4],
        ['Oranges', 2]
      ]
    }, {
      id: 'cars',
      data: [
        ['Toyota', 4],
        ['Opel', 2],
        ['Volkswagen', 2]
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drilldown mechanism in Highcharts is responsible only for handling series, but it launches `drilldown` and `dillup` events which can be used for applying updates:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      drilldown: function() {
        this.xAxis[0].update({
          labels: {
            enabled: false
          }
        });
      },
      drillup: function() {
        this.xAxis[0].update({
          labels: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }, false);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/11qhaffe/

---

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drillup